# Why are global and this.something variables not decleared?

Tags: javascript, extjs

When I used a **new** variable something.something or this.something, my code worked when I omitted the var keyword:

```
this.something = 1;
something.something = 1;
```

but when I write

```
var this.something = 1;
var something.something = 1;
```

it doesn't work.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose because `var` expects a valid identifier, and `.` is not a valid character for an identifier.

It thinks you want the variable name to actually be `this.something`, which isn't valid.

---

When testing the two versions, I get slightly different errors.

The one with `this.something` tells me:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token this

The one with `something.something` tells me:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Same error, but the invalid token in the first is the keyword `this`.

Comment: Do you get these errors with the var statement?
I should say that I have a the something namespace defined
Ext.ns('something');

Comment: @ppecher: Yes, with the `var`. That is a keyword meant for declaring variables. If you were hoping to use the value stored in `something.something` as the variable name, you'll be out of luck unless you're talking about global variables, which are all properties of `window`. In that case, you could do `window[something.something]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare a `this` field (member field), or a field of another object.  It's simply not valid syntax.

You use `var` to declare local variables, which are either function-level or (if you're not in a function) global.  And as Patrick said, a variable name can not contain a period.

Answer (score 0):

`var` is the syntax for declaring a variable.  In Javascript simply by assigning a value to a property it will attach the property to the object.